# Hosting a Laravel app with multipule subdomains on nginx vps host

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VPS which I am hosting a Laravel app with a forum  section routed on a subdomain. The main section of the site is routed to the TLD.

I was able to configure Nginx to serve my main site content when I go to www.example.com, however, when I go to forum.example.com, the site's IP address cannot be found

Here is my Godaddy configuration: https://pasteboard.co/IP3XM3n.png

Here is my nginx configuration file:

```
    listen 80;


    root /var/www/intransportal/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name intransportal.com forum.intransportal.com;

      location @rewrite {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
        }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

And here are my routes

```
$domain = parse_url(config('app.url'), PHP_URL_HOST);
Route::domain('forum.'.$domain)->group(function() {
    Route::get('/threads/', 'ThreadsController@index');
    Route::get('/threads/create', 'ThreadsController@create');
    Route::get('/threads/{channel}/{thread}', 'ThreadsController@show');
    Route::delete('/threads/{channel}/{thread}', 'ThreadsController@destroy');
    Route::post('/threads', 'ThreadsController@store');
    Route::get('/threads/{channel}/{thread}/replies','RepliesController@index');
    Route::post('/threads/{channel}/{thread}/replies','RepliesController@store');
    Route::get('/threads/{channel}', 'ThreadsController@index');
    Route::patch('/replies/{reply}', 'RepliesController@update');
    Route::delete('/replies/{reply}', 'RepliesController@destroy');
    Route::post('/replies/{reply}/favorite', 'FavoritesController@store');
    Route::delete('/replies/{reply}/favorite','FavoritesController@destroy');
    Route::get('/', 'ThreadsController@index');
    Route::patch('/replies/{reply}', 'RepliesController@update');

});
Route::get('/','HomeController@index');
Auth::routes();
Route::get('profiles/{user}', 'ProfilesController@show')->name('profile');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotosController');
```

How to I point the forum's routes to my subdomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `CNAME` record for subdomain.

```
+-----------------------+
| Type    Name    Value |
+-----------------------+
| CNAME   forum   @     |
+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. Give me a bit for the nameservers to update, then I will let you know if that worked.